# Query to compare values across different tables?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a pair of models in my Rails app that I'm having trouble bridging.

These are the tables I'm working with:

states

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id |  fips  |    name    |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 | 06     | California |
|  2 | 36     | New York   |
|  3 | 48     | Texas      |
|  4 | 12     | Florida    |
|  5 | 17     | Illinois   |
|  … | …      |    …       |
+----+--------+------------+
```

places

```
+----+--------+
| id | place  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Fl     |
|  2 | Calif. |
|  3 | Texas  |
|  … |   …    |
+----+--------+
```

Not all places are represented in the states model, but I'm trying to perform a query where I can compare a place's `place` value against all state `name`s, find the closest match, and return the corresponding `fips`.

So if my input is `Calif.`, I want my output to be `06`

I'm still very new to writing SQL queries, so if there's a way to do this using Ruby within my Rails (4.1.5) app, that would be ideal.

My other plan of attack was to add a `fips` column to the "places" table, and write something that would run the above comparison and then populate `fips` so my app doesn't have to run this query every the page loads. But I'm very much a beginner, so that sounds... ambitious.

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to the abbreviations in the `places.place` field?

Comment: Before considering SQL, you need to determine, generically, what kind of matching scheme can get you from the `place` in `places` to the `name` in `states`.

Comment: For the *most* part, it'll look something like `places.place` = `Florida State` and `states.name` = `Florida`. Not always, but in enough cases, that'll be the convention.

Comment: why haven't you created a relation between the 2 models ? it would be easier

Comment: I have places `belongs_to :states` in my `models/places.rb`, but I'm not sure how to set up the relationship here beyond that. Places is something like 3,000 records.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an easy query in SQL.  Your best bet is one of the fuzzing string matching routines, which are documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html).

For instance, `soundex()` or `levenshtein()` may be sufficient for what you want.  Here is an example:

```
select distinct on (p.place) p.place, s.name, s.fips, levenshtein(p.place, s.name) as dist
from places p cross join
     states s
order by p.place, dist asc;
```